# Bamboo - How can I share environment modules between tasks in a job without loading them for every task?

Tags: scripting, task, environment, bamboo, environment-modules

My plan consists of many jobs and many script tasks in each of those jobs.

Most of these script tasks rely on the same 5 or 6 modules that I am loading every time, for example:

```
module load python/argparse_py2.7/1.2.1
module load python/python/2.7.13
```

Instead of having to load these environment modules for every task, is there a way to load them once and have all subsequent tasks be able to access them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you load a module from a script or an interactive shell session, this module stays loaded for the rest of the script or session and it is also still loaded in the context of sub-script launched by the main one or sub-shells launched by the main session.

So in a script context where you launch many sub-tasks/scripts, you should put your `module load` commands near the beginning of the script to get those modules enables for the rest of the execution or sub-executions.

This is also valid for an interactive shell session.

In addition, new versions of the `module` command [provide a way](https://modules.readthedocs.io/en/stable/module.html#module-sub-commands) to `save` a loaded module context and `restore` it later on (in script or in other shell sessions).

Here is a small example for module collection usage:

```
$ module purge
$ module load python/argparse_py2.7/1.2.1 python/python/2.7.13
$ module save pythonjobenv
$ module savelist
Named collection list:
 1) pythonjobenv
$ module purge
$ module restore pythonjobenv
Restoring collection pythonjobenv
  Loading module: python/argparse_py2.7/1.2.1 python/python/2.7.13
```